# match exact item of array or only exact the combination of array items _ MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

suppose we have an array of some string. there is a use case It has to be done.

```
let myArray = ['a', 'g', 'd', 'e']

let collections = [

    {items:['a', 'b']},  ==> false

    {items:['a', 'g']}, ==> true

    {items:['d', 'f']},  ==> false

    {items:['a', 'g', 'd', 'e']}, ==> true

    {items:['a', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'o']}, ==> false

    {items:['a', 'g','e']}, ==> true

    {items:['g']}, ==> true

    {items:['g', 'k']}, ==> false
]
```

my goals:

1. only exact match with one item.
2. match the only combination of these items.

first of all, I know this query is so expensive cause for every item of this array we have factorial of that query match.

if we have 2 elements in our array we have 2 possible queries. if we have **4** elements we have **4 * 3 * 2 * 1** possible queries.

my second question is: is this relevant? **beside of the use case**.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            filteredCollections: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$collections",
                    as: "collection",
                    cond: {
                       $setIsSubset: [
                          ["$$collection.items"],
                          ["a", "g", "d", "e"]
                       ]
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "filteredCollections.0": {$exists: true}
        }
    }
])
```

For exact match you can use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) combined with `$setIsSubset`.

Comment: tnx for reply but I get this error: errmsg: 'The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: bool',

Comment: It's mb. i merged two pipelines i was testing with and did not notice. let me edit it real quick. you should use only the setIsSubset without the $size and $gt.

Comment: I also changed `collections` to `$collections` in the input as it's the required syntax.

Comment: i get empty result . my item are array of objects . but in js I am passing only array of strings

Comment: You need to post the database schema then so i can see what it is. unless you want to do this in code and then your question shouldn't be tagged as a `Mongod` question. but it sounds like using `$map` on the `items` array will solve the issue.

Comment: const myModelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    
    items: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Some_collection",
        require: true
    }]
});

Comment: `item` is an array of `ObjectId` from your schema. not of objects.